# Prove that 1 is the only real number which satisfies $|x-1|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ for every $n \in N$

Tags: calculus

Prove that 1 is the only real number which satisfies $|x-1|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ for every $n \in N$

Here's how I would do this problem:

First I noticed that $|x-1|\geq 0$ for all $x \in R$

So suppose that $|x-1|\neq 0$ now I can use the Archimedean property which states that $∀x∈R:∃m∈N:m>x$

But how do I go upon picking an $x$. From the resource I'm using they state that $\frac{1}{|x-1|} \in R$ and by the Archimedean property there exist an $m \in N$ such that $$m>\frac{1}{|x-1|}$$

Since $m^2\geq m$ for $m \in N$, they deduce that

$$m^2>\frac{1}{|x-1|}$$

which implies

$$|x-1| > \frac{1}{m^2}$$

Do you just pick an $x \in R$ satisfying $|x-1| \neq 0$ or is there a specified $x$ and if there is how do we come up with it? *in other words how did they get $\frac{1}{|x-1|} \in R$*

Comment: In my view, you shouldn't think about picking $x$. You should rather think: let $x$ be given and fixed (any arbitrary, given, fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$). Then you can reason about the world in case $x=1$ and in case $x\neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x-1|< \frac{1}{n^2}$ is equivalent to $1-\frac{1}{n^2}<x<1+\frac{1}{n^2}$. For each number $x\neq 1$, there exists $n$ large enough such that $x$ is not in the small interval around $1$ defined by our inequality.

More formally: Let $x=1+\epsilon$, for any $\epsilon\neq 0$ fixed; wlog let $\epsilon>0$. Apparently, there exists $n$ large enough such that $\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon$. Hence, $x\notin (1-1/n^2,1+1/n^2)$.

Comment: This gives the intuition, but proves nothing.

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: "There exists $n$ large enough..." Proof? You're just restating what the OP wants.

Comment: But this is entirely trivial - I will edit it ...

Comment: Well, it is not to the asker, else the question wouldn't exist. =)

Comment: Well, I didn't mean the question was trivial, I meant to conclude the proof, from what I have written, was entirely trivial.

Comment: I think the whole point of the proof is figuring out how large we have to choose $n$ for a given $x\neq 1$.

Comment: No, of course not. This is not what the question demands.

Comment: I have upvoted now. =)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\neq 1$, then $\left|x-1\right|=\varepsilon>0$, choose any $n>\sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}$, then $n^2>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ so $\varepsilon > \frac{1}{n^2}$. Thus we have
$$
\left|x-1\right| = \varepsilon > \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
So it is not true that $\left|x-1\right|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

For $x=1$ we have
$$\left|x-1\right| = 0 <\frac{1}{n^2}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Your proof is alright, of course, but how can you have earned so many points and think that the task is to \emph{also} specify $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$? Nowhere is this stated in the question. Giving additional information is not bad, of course, but it doesn't necessarily go along with the principle of mathematical economy.

Comment: @mathse You claim "There exists $n$ large enough such that $\frac{1}{n^2} < \varepsilon$", why is that true? I don't think "apparently" is the way to go on this level.

Comment: Well, he himself said that he (or his book) uses the "Archimedean property" for this: If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then there exists a natural number $n_x$ such that $x<n_x$. So, in my proof, since $\epsilon>0$, also $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{R}$, whence there exists $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and also $n^2\ge n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ (which is equivalent to my condition). He said this himself ...

Comment: @mathse If you use it, of course. I also used it to choose $n>\sqrt{1/\varepsilon}$. But at some point you have to prove there is such $n$, which is exactly what I did. I don't see how this is supposed to be "additional information" and why you question my ways of earning reputation.

Comment: I questioned your number of points because you said "I think the whole point of the proof is figuring out how large we have to choose n for a given $x≠1$" - and we don't have to do this. As you now admit, we only have to show that there is such $n$.

Comment: There is no way to show that there is such $n$ without figuring out how big it needs to be, though. And as you said yourself, your argument uses $n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, so you had to figure out how big to choose $n$ as well.

Comment: So, we have a fundamental disagreement here, it seems. Look back at the AP: it says that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is an integer $n>x$. It doesn't say how large you have to choose $n$ (unless you wish to say "you have to choose $n>x$" - but this is a circular statement)...

Comment: And the AP really **is** a way to show an integer $n>x$ exists without figuring out how big it needs to be.

Comment: In order to have $\frac{1}{n^2}<\varepsilon$, you have to choose $n$ large enough, both $n>\sqrt{1/\varepsilon}$ and $n>1/\varepsilon$ are sufficient to get this. That such $n$ exists is given by AP, I did use that implicit as well. No disagreement here whatsoever.

Comment: Exactly, that such an $n$ exists can be given by an existence proof. That such an $n$ has to satisfy $n>A$ is an additional piece of information that you don't need to provide ...

Comment: Then please prove there is an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n^2} < \varepsilon$ without making a statement about how large $n$ should be for me.

Comment: Alright, I see your point that such a proof can entail, as a byproduct, a bound.

Comment: But it need not. Where does the AP come from? Alternatively to the AP, we could directly setup a property CP: for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon$, right? A proof by contradiction of the AP can be found here http://www.ithaca.edu/seltzer/analysis/archimedean.pdf

Comment: This shows that you really don't need to specify an upper bound ...

Comment: So, you can think of my result $1/n^2<\epsilon$ as derived from the AP, in which case a bound would have been produced, or as based on the CP, for which a similar contradiction proof (or other alternative proof) can be established as given in the link ...

Comment: To add to this. Either you consider the AP to be trivial, then you can also state the CP to be trivial, without proof, in which case no bound is required. If you think this must be proven, then AP and CP are clearly equivalent, so you could come up with a direct proof of each. But then you cannot add any bounds - i.e. to prove that there exists $n$ such that $n>x$ you cannot simply say "use $n>x$" - because this is what you have to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit was small but rather substantial: the answer to the new question is that $|x-1|\neq 0$ and therefore $\frac1{|x-1|}$ is the multiplicative inverse of a nonzero real number. By the field axioms, this must also be a real number.

One useful way to think about how the number $x$ is obtained is that it is chosen by your "enemy": you have no way of knowing what it will be, just that it is not $1$, and if there is any way in which it can be chosen to make your life difficult, it will be.

Answer (score -1):

Note that for $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n > 2$ you have
$$\frac1{n^2} < \frac1{2^2} = \frac14 < 2 < n$$
Wich proves the statement for all $n>2$. For $n=2$ you can trivially verify and so you are done.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote?